# Use a method in Regex.Replace()

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem. I have some text that I want to parse. The problem is I find it using regular expressions:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\(DOWN\)\(LShift\)(.*?)\(UP\)\(LShift\)", "$1");
```

I want to parse each letter from `$1` value into something using my method. But the input for this method isn't `$1` variable value but a string of value `"$1"`.

I tried:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\(DOWN\)\(LShift\)(.*?)\(UP\)\(LShift\)", ShiftsParser("$1"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx). Example using a lambda:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match => 
{
    // $1 is equivalent to match.Groups[1].Value,
    // so do whatever you want and return the value here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should take a Match object as the parameter.

```
string ShiftsParser(Match match)
{
    string value = match.Groups[1].Value;  // $1 value.
    // Do some work with value
    return value;
}
```

I hope this help.